# Proposed Question - Degrees of Internet Connectivity?

Tags: discussion

I've heard about something like Degrees of Kevin Bacon, but for the web, a maximum number of links from one webpage to any other webpage on the Internet...

Is there any truth to the idea that if I drew a site map of the whole Internet, it's a connected graph?

Assuming I make my sitemap by only crawling through hyperlinks, that is...?

[19 Clicks of Separation News Article (2013)](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/any-two-pages-on-the-web-are-connected-by-19-clicks-or-less-19517004/?no-ist) - [Original Paper (1999)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v401/n6749/abs/401130a0.html)

Hmm... Anything newer?

Comment: cool stuff eh? there are many dimensions to this... see eg [pagerank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagerank)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this post. It does not seem to be a (good) question for the main site, and it's definitely not a meta question.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to ask if this is a good question for the Main site, which you have answered, thank you! ... (For more info on what I'm trying to do here, go to Worldbuilding's Question Sandbox?) ... ... Now, what makes my question a bad question? Oh... Perhaps I should specify hyperlinks, that can be clicked on by a viewer!

Comment: Our [help] has more information about how to ask a good question.  See especially http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  It often helps to show us what your thoughts are and what research you've done or what attempts you've made to answer the question on your own.  For instance, you might start by asking yourself "what could cause it to be *not* connected? can that happen?".

Comment: It's not exactly what you're referring to, but then this is not the right forum :-) [Single links mostly take you to one place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy) but within a single website.